# set specific name to file downloaded with get_url in ansible

Tags: ansible

I've this task in my playbook

```
- name: get file
  get_url:
    url: "{{ file_url }}"
    dest: .
  environment:
    https_proxy: "{{ proxy }}"
```

can i download this file with a other specific name ?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#parameter-dest

You can set `dest` to the desired filename.  Since you have `dest` set to a directory, the following applies:

> If dest is a directory, either the server provided filename or, if none provided, the base name of the URL on the remote server will be used. If a directory, force has no effect.

Change it to a file path and you can control the name of the file.